# Is $\cos^3{x}$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I've found proofs that a continuous mapping from a bounded set to $\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, but is it true the other way? If not, how do you go about proving or disproving uniform continuity?

Comment: To be precise, the theorem you quote (Heine-Cantor) states that a continuous map from a bounded *closed* subset of $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: In this particular case of $\cos^3$, you can show it's Lipschitz -- using the fact that it's continuously differentiable with bounded derivative.

Comment: It is continuous on the closed interval $[0,2\pi]$ so uniformly continuous there. The rest follows from the fact our function is periodic.

Comment: $\cos^3x$ = $\dfrac{\cos 3x+3\cos x}{4}$

Comment: A continuous mapping from a bounded set to $\Bbb R $ need not be uniformly continuous. Consider $f:x\mapsto \frac1x$ on $(0,1)\to \Bbb R$. Continuous mappings on _compact_ domains are uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

When you have to claim if a function is UC or not you have also to say *where* it is. In this case we have two situations: A) Bounded sets
                                         B) Unbounded sets

Let $f(x)= cos^3(x)$
Case A) If we have a bounded set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ then it is contained in the interval $ [-n,n]$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and now, applying [Heine-Cantor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem), we have the uniform continuity of $f(x)$

Case B) In this case we can consider $\mathbb{R}$ as the only set remained, we can check that the derivative of $f(x)$ which is $f'(x)= -3cos^2(x)sin(x)$ is  bounded, and so we can see, using the mean value theorem, that the function is UC